# Can you identify this Illinois wasp?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, wasps

I live in northern Illinois and had these guys appearing in my room. No facial markings and they seem non agressive.

About 2cm in length with off white u shaped markings below it's waist and a single white line a few segments down.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me as [Potter Wasp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potter_wasp) (or mason wasps), the Eumeninae, are a cosmopolitan wasp group presently treated as a subfamily of Vespidae, but sometimes recognized in the past as a separate family, Eumenidae.

Since there is no more info provided and image is not sharp I cannot be 100% sure.

Comment: The post displays info about its size now which was previously hidden due to improper usage of markdown.

Comment: The online _Canadian Journal of Arthropod Identification_ has an issue covering the *Vespidae* of northeastern North America (PDF available here: http://biologicalsurvey.ca/ejournal/bmc_05/pdf/bmc05.pdf), with Illinois as a limital point; if you have a stereoscope available and are willing to take a specimen (freezing will work, if you don't want to use poisons), you will get a species name from that work.